# stop clang format from breaking lines

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I want to change the behaviour below (left is how it should be and right is how its turning out)

[image: example1]

[image: example_images]

This is my current `.clang-format`:

```
---
AlignConsecutiveMacros: 'true'
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: 'true'
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: 'true'
AlignTrailingComments: 'true'
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: 'false'
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: 'false'
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: 'false'
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: 'false'
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: 'true'
BinPackArguments: 'false'
BinPackParameters: 'false'
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
IndentWidth: '4'
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: 'true'
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: 'true'
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: 'true'
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: 'false'
SpacesInAngles: 'false'
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: 'false'
SpacesInContainerLiterals: 'false'
SpacesInParentheses: 'false'
Standard: Latest
TabWidth: '0'
UseTab: Never
PointerAlignment: Left
ColumnLimit: 0


...
```

It correctly puts function defenitions and parameters on the same line but it does not do the same for function calls and for loops as example.

Comment: In the second example, how is clang-format supposed to distinguish which parameters belong on their own line, and which should be batched together? The two string literals are not special. With `ColumnLimit: 0` there is no notion of something being "long".

Comment: That should be the behavior tho, everything should not be too long so it won’t get their own line, they are all supposed to be on one line

Comment: `BinPack*` should be true, then. You want them packed.

Comment: I will try that once I’m home

Comment: @raizo But you "desired" example uses three lines. If you put all 5 arguments on the same line, then `clang-format` would keep it as is. However, it "sees" you putting arguments on multiple lines, and conforms to that. "Oh, you want multiple lines? Fine, every argument on its own line then. No half-measures"

Comment: @Frank well how would I configure it that way that it will not conform to that but actively changes that

Comment: @raizo, `BinPackArguments: 'true'` *might* get you closer, but then again, it will most likely not give you exactly what you want either,

Comment: I will try that later and reply with my results

Comment: @Frank https://i.imgur.com/GS2GKfL.png setting them both to true also wont change it

Comment: this also seems to make the function declarations put the parameters on different lines with `BinPackArguments: 'true'
BinPackParameters: 'true'`