# Can clang-format be instructed to maintain newlines in a function call parameter list?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

For example, in Go, the following is a correctly go-fmt'ed code

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World",
        "some",
        "more", "args", "s",
        "Bye World")
}
```

I am able to have groups of parameters share a line and go-fmt will not second-guess me. This is IMO sensible when some parameters are related to each other and I can express that by having them share a line in the call.

On the other hand, clang-format insists either on bin-packing the parameter list, or placing every parameter on its own line, with no middle ground.

```cpp
    Println("Hello World", "some", "more", "args", "s", "Bye World")
```

or

```cpp
    Println("Hello World",
            "some",
            "more",
            "args",
            "s",
            "Bye World")
```

Is this how it is, or can clang-format be instructed to behave the go-fmt way in regards to these "preformatted" parameter lists?

My question is quite similar to [stop clang format from breaking lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365920/stop-clang-format-from-breaking-lines), except I believe I am expressing the specific goal here: preserve line breaks in the original parameter list (as long as it does not conflict with line length limits, etc).

Comment: There's always https://stackoverflow.com/a/25642688/4641116

Comment: Adding `// comments` at the end of the individual lines with parameters also preserves the newlines.

Comment: Indeed, that is the convention that my dev team uses just to thwart **clang-format** from reformatting those kinds of multi-line constructs.  At least we use the artificial comments to add useful notes.  But still sort of a bother.